# how to use context inside the Service?

Tags: android

I have used this code for my service.

```
 View v1 = (Activity)getApplicationContext()).
                          getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

But getting the error like this

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application 
                                cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Comment: a `Service` is  a `Context` - see its base class

Comment: I added like what you told but cannot access the  getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(); inside the service

Comment: `java.lang.Object < android.content.Context < android.content.ContextWrapper < android.app.Service` - as you can see a `Service` indirectly extends a `Context`

Comment: this is because a `Service` does not have `getWindow()` method - it is an `Activity` method, not `Context`

Comment: I need to call this for every 5 seconds in background . View v1 = (Activity)getApplicationContext()).
                          getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Comment: i say that `Service` does NOT have `getWindow()` method - there is `Activity#getWindow()` method, NOT `Service#getWindow()`

Answer (score 0):

you can't use getWindow in the service because it related to UI thread instead you can use WindowManger

Comment: it has little to do with UI thread: a `Service` by default is running in UI thread too

Comment: service is UI and has context itself I mean not have the layout like activity and getwindow mean to get the layout on the current activity

Comment: first at all it does not have `getWindow()` method

Comment: Yes bro :D :D :D

Comment: Hi my query is i need to take screenshot for every 5 mintues in Background while app is terminated. Here the code i wrote.   View v1 = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();...Then how to use this code in background service.

Comment: @Sarvan My information that you can't take a screenshot on background service "only you can on rooted devices", actually that for security purpose.

but if you want to take a screenshot for your app screens  you can implement broadcast receiver between your service and the activities and when your condition done in your service call the broadcast to fire screenshot